# Timer to pass from h1 to h6

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

Hy everyboy. I've a problem to make and i'm blocked.
I must write a function that every 1000ms call itself and increase or decrease periodically heading level from H1 to H6 and then back to H1 in Javascript code.
How can i make?
I've done an example as this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",1000);
}
function alertMsg()
{
alert("Hello");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert every seconds"
onclick="timeMsg()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an interval, not a timeout. Also, you can simply pass the function to be executed to `setInterval`. Try this:

```js
    var
        interval,
        startLoop = function()
        {
            interval = window.setInterval(function(){
            alert("Hello");
            }, 1000);
        };
    
    document.getElementById("startbutton").addEventListener("click", startLoop);
```

```html
<button id="startbutton">Let’s go</button>
```

Referencing the interval through the `interval` variable, allows to cancel the interval later:

```
// some time later …
window.clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to change the size of some element, using 1 second intervals. Well, you can not convert an HTML element into something else, meaning H1 will always be H1, and never become H2.

What you can do is set a few classes, and change which class that element should use.

```js
var t=setInterval(changeClass,1000);
var n=0;

function changeClass(){
n++;
document.getElementById("theElement").className = "type"+n;
if (n>=4) n=0;
}
```

```css
.type1 {font-size:10px;}
.type2 {font-size:15px;}
.type3 {font-size:20px;}
.type4 {font-size:25px;}
```

```html
<div id=theElement>
This is the header
</div>
```

There many other ways of doing this, depending on what you expect to achieve.

Comment: Are you sure that is no possibile convert an HTML element into something else?

Comment: Pretty sure, i started learning HTML around 1995. You can´t change an element, you can only change its properties. The .type codes are CSS  declarations (see .type1, .type2...)